# Open my iPhone app from the url received in sms

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, sms

I want to launch my application from the url received to user via an sms.

How do I achieve it?

The format of my url is:
https://companyname.net/productname/?some_parameters_for_user

I want to prompt user to open url in safari or my app and depending on his choice, the app will be launched either in safari or directly the native app.

The url opens in safari but how to invoke native app? and take user to a particular page in app?

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the custom URL scheme. It's described in several places. Here is a link to "[Advanced App Tricks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html)"

It's described there, along with many other helpful ideas.